# Error ITMS-9000: Missing or invalid signature. AFTER updating from OS X 10.8 to 10.9

Tags: xcode, codesign

We have an automated build system that has been running on OSX 10.8 (Mac Mini - Xcode 5.1.1) perfectly until after we updated to 10.9 (Mac Pro - Xcode 5.1.1).

After updating to OSX 10.9 we started receiving the following error when we attempt to upload our IPA via Application Loader:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle 'com.my.bundle" at bundle path "Payload/bundle.app" is not signed using an Apple submission certificate."
```

The following statements are ran after Unity has built the Xcode project.

```
xcodebuild -target "Unity-iPhone" -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: Company Name, Inc. (DDXX7YXXXX)" PROVISIONING_PROFILE=d5e4xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5fef0dbe3e50;

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "$IOS_RELEASE_SAVE_PATH/build/bundle.app" -o "IOS_IPA_PATH/bundle_RELEASE.ipa" --sign "Company Name, Inc. (DDXX7YXXXX)" --embed "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/d5e4xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5fef0dbe3e50.mobileprovision";
```

As a side note, our ADHOC builds are signed using the same certificate, just a different provision, and work fine.

I double checked the following items:

- Project and Provision bundle ids match. (Case sensitivity and potential character replacements.)
- Certificates & Provisions are up to date.
- Distribution Certs are marked as TRUSTED to all users.

I also built the IPA manually and attempted to submit, but resulted with the same error.

Other options I have tried:

- Adding '--deep' to 'Other Code Signning Flags' in both Project and Targets.
- Adding a `codesign` script to `Build Phases` [(Code Signing and Mavircks: furbo.org)](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Added - Distribution Certs are marked as TRUSTED to all users & Platform model/Xcode version.

Comment: I'm also getting this error and haven't found a solution yet.  Started after upgrading to xcode 6.

Comment: Sadly, the only way I was able to resolve this issue was to rebuild the entire build server from scratch.  I hope someone is able to find an actual solution for the described errors.

Comment: I ended up creating a new user and was able to get it working after downloading the certificates into the new user's keychain.

Comment: Thanks Twilly, add your previous comment as an answer.  If someone ups it, I'll mark it as 'the' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time, but I encountered this issue again when updating from OSX 10.9 Mavericks & Xcode 5.1.1 to OSX 10.10 & Xcode 6.1.1.

Solution (similar to TWilly's comment):

**NOTE: BACKUP .p12 keys and certs as needed!**

- Reset Keychain to System Defaults and purge all Provision Profiles from iPhone Configuration Utility.
- Retrieve your .p12 key and Provisions from the Developer Portal.
- Apply your publishing and development certs to SYSTEM (not login).
- Attempt to build from command line.

Additionally, building from CL on OSX 10.10 and XCODE6 may introduce an issue:  “ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources”

See [this link for solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516442/how-do-we-manually-fix-resourcerules-plist-cannot-read-resources-error-after/26747620#26747620).