# How do we manually fix "ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources" error after xcode 6.1 upgrade?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, unity-game-engine, xcode6.1

We are having the same issue found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497863/xcode-6-1-error-while-building-ipa-using-testflight-app/26499526#26499526), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500558/packageapplication-stopped-working-with-os-x-10-10-yosemite-today), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138525/xcode-sharing-app-packageapplication-failed-with-exit-code-1) and [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1052189#1052189)

Basically we upgraded to xcode 6.1 and our build are getting the "ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources" error.

We have a Jenkins server that does our ios builds for us.  We are using the [Xcode plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin) on Jenkins to do the actual build and signing.  Any thoughts on how we can make this change without manually opening xcode and doing this solution found on the other answers:

> Click on your project > Targets > Select your target > Build Settings >
>
> Code Signing Resource Rules Path
>
> and add :
>
> $(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist

I'm very new to Xcode and iOS build in general.  I have found the project.pbxproj file inside the Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj file.  It looks like this contains the build settings under the **/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */** section it lists what looks like similar build properties foundin Xcode, however I do not see anything like "Code Signing Resource Rules Path".

Does anyone have experience manually editing this file?  Is that a bad idea in general?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 6.1 error while building IPA using TestFlight app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497863/xcode-6-1-error-while-building-ipa-using-testflight-app)

Comment: The accepted fix in that thread requires the ability to edit the xcode project via the gui. It appears that this issue is with Unity built xcode projects running through a Jenkins based CI solution. This means that the xcode projects are auto generated and auto built without the chance or desire for manual manipulation of the xcode project.

Comment: Yes, @jpelletier it is with a Unity built xcode project that is then built through command line, we never manually open the project up.

Comment: @PeterMetz I referenced that same thread in my original post, however as jpelletier pointed out, those require manual intervention of opening the project, we never do that.

Comment: @Tim I'm sorry, my bad! Should've read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you're using Jenkins with the XCode plugin, you can modify the `'Code Signing Resource Rules Path'` variable by adding:

```
"CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH=$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist"
```

to the

`'Custom xcodebuild arguments'` setting for the XCode plugin.

This fix does not require the XCode GUI.

Comment: Thanks nick That was too easy, not sure how I didn't see that.  Worked great! I am sure @martinmose script would have worked, just saw this before I tried it.  Also for anyone else using Unity, I had a third option I was going to try using their [XcodeAPI](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/xcodeapi) to change it.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you are using Yosemite, the above is obsolete. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497863/xcode-6-1-error-while-building-ipa/26674605#26674605

Comment: Works but not recommended. See the link for the fix : http://cutting.io/posts/packaging-ios-apps-from-the-command-line/

Comment: This is broken again on XCode 8.0. Does anyone have any fixes for this?

Comment: Hi @c0d3Junk13 , any luck in integration with xcode 8, I have similar issue.

Comment: Hi @BurhanMughal, we turned of automatic code signing on our build machine which is under the General tab of the project in Xcode 8.

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 Got the Solution but not the one you are proposing :) I had already turned off automatic signing. But What actually work was to manually go to PackageApplication and removing/commenting the ResourceRules.plist line. Anyway thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Ah ok glad, I was a bit out of context to be honest.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same problem. Nicks solution does work, but is requiring additional dependencies. You don't need the heavy-handed *npm xcode* module for this. Just add a line to this file:
**$PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig**

```
CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH=$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist
```

Note that before XCode 6.1.1, this needed to be specified as `"$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist"` (notice the quotes).

If you are running this inside automated build systems such as Jenkins and wont't/can't use any XCode GUI, just create a small Cordova hook, leveraging npm's [fs.appendFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback), at this location:
**$PROJECT_ROOT/hooks/before_build/ios_resourcerules.js** (make sure it has chmod +x)

```
#! /usr/local/bin/node
var fs = require("fs");

fs.appendFileSync('build.xcconfig', '\nCODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH =  $(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist', function (err) {
 if (err) throw err;
  console.log('CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH added to Cordova iOS build configuration.');
});
```

This will <strike>might</strike> be merged in an upcoming Cordova release, so the hook will become unnecessary (<strike>i'm creating a</strike> see [this PR for Cordova-iOS](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7872)).

In case the above JavaScript snippet fails to execute due to a "wrong argument" failure, replace the file's content as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f ./build.xcconfig ]; then
  echo "[ERROR] hook befor_build/ios_resourcerules.sh cannot execute, ./build/xcconfig not found in $PWD"
  exit 1
fi

echo '// (CB-7872) Solution for XCode 6.1 signing errors related to resource envelope format deprecation' >> ./build.xcconfig
echo 'CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH=$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist' >> ./build.xcconfig
echo 'CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH added to Cordova iOS build configuration.'
```

Comment: For what it's worth, cordova requires the xcode module, so you'll likely already have it around, though I too am not a fan of the module.

Comment: With your code you'll see an error "Bad arguments".
Because you use the synchronous function fs.appendFileSync with a callback.
To use the callback, use fs.appendFile instead.

Comment: Awesome thank you! This worked for me (editing the build.xcconfig file). I only had to make one minor change removing the quotes from "$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist"

Comment: Is the Cordova bug fix working for anyone? Like @jarbot, I had to remove the quotes from the line that Cordova had added to the build.xcconfig file.

Comment: @nick's solution worked great for us without needing any additional dependancies. I'm confused as to where npm or Cordova enter into the question, though…

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get really crazy, you can directly update PackageApplication.

```
# In /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication
my @codesign_args = ("/usr/bin/codesign", "--force", "--preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules",
                     "--sign", $opt{sign},
                     "--resource-rules=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/ResourceRules.plist");
# OLD:               "--resource-rules=$destApp/ResourceRules.plist");
```

I was already hacking this script to accept a keychain arg, so it made sense for me. Note I'm not using the Xcode Jenkins plugin -- I'm using Jenkins but running all the build commands from a script.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this works even if you're using the Jenkins Xcode plugin

Comment: This gives "Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!"

Answer (score 4):

After the new release of XCode 7 on 23rd Sept 2015, Apple started rejecting any application that is using `CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH`, making the Jenkins build automatically rejected. However, setting `CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH=$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist` into the Custom xcodebuild arguments causes a build failure.

This answer resolved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762413/5373468

This is clearly a bug that Apple forgot to fix a while ago, as this article is also highlighting: http://cutting.io/posts/packaging-ios-apps-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 1):

I had EXACTLY the same problem, as you have. We are building our iOS app on Jenkins, so we couldn't manually set "Code Signing Resource Rules Path".

I have wrote a small NodeJS file which does the job for me **(see the code below)**.

The script use a nice NodeJS package called [xcode](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xcode) which helps me with the parsing of the xcode.xcodeproj file.

I don't know if you are using Cordova/Phonegap or what you are using, but if you are can just copy the code and make a Cordova hook. If not I'm sure you can execute the file from Jenkins, with some small changes.

Anyways, I hope this script will help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH = '"$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist"';

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var xcode = require('xcode');
var projectRoot = process.argv[2];

function getProjectName(protoPath) {
    var cordovaConfigPath = path.join(protoPath, 'www', 'config.xml');
    var content = fs.readFileSync(cordovaConfigPath, 'utf-8');

    return /<name>([\s\S]*)<\/name>/mi.exec(content)[1].trim();
}

function run(projectRoot) {
    var projectName = getProjectName(projectRoot);
    var xcodeProjectName = projectName + '.xcodeproj';
    var xcodeProjectPath = path.join(projectRoot, 'platforms', 'ios', xcodeProjectName, 'project.pbxproj');
    var xcodeProject;

    if (!fs.existsSync(xcodeProjectPath)) {
        return;
    }

    xcodeProject = xcode.project(xcodeProjectPath);

    console.log('Setting Code Sign Resource Rules Path for ' + projectName + ' to: [' + CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH + '] ...');
    xcodeProject.parse(function(error){
        if(error){
            console.log('An error occured during parsing of [' + xcodeProjectPath + ']: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }else{
            var configurations = nonComments(xcodeProject.pbxXCBuildConfigurationSection());
            for (config in configurations) {
                var buildSettings = configurations[config].buildSettings;

                buildSettings['CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH'] = CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH;
            }

            fs.writeFileSync(xcodeProjectPath, xcodeProject.writeSync(), 'utf-8');

            console.log('[' + xcodeProjectPath + '] now has Code Signing Resource Rules Path set to:[' + CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH + '] ...');
        }
    });
}

var COMMENT_KEY = /_comment$/;
function nonComments(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj),
        newObj = {}, i = 0;

    for (i; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (!COMMENT_KEY.test(keys[i])) {
            newObj[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
        }
    }

    return newObj;
}

run(projectRoot);
```

Comment: We are actually using Unity3D, everything is written in C#.  I can run a postprocess script once the Unity build is complete.  That would happen after the xcode project is generated, but before it is compiled into the app.  I may be able to fairly easily change your nodejs script to C# and just kick it off after the Unity build is done.  I'll give it a shot and if it works mark yours as the answer.  Thanks for the script!

Comment: matinmose thanks for the script! @Tim, can you post your c# script once you write it please?

Answer (score 1):

We are using Unity + Jenkins for auto builds.

You can achieve with post process cs scripts; however; for quick (and dirty fix) you can apply following bash command after Unity but before xcode:

```
sed -i '' 's/CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH = "\$(SDKROOT)\/ResourceRules\.plist";\'$'\n                CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/g' /Users/admin/Jenkins/workspace/PROJECTNAME/Build/PROJECTNAME/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```