# Xcode 7 Code Signing Resource Rules Path issue

Tags: app-store-connect, ios9, xcode7

I have the latest Xcode 7 and iOS 9 SDK installed on my El Caption. I just get an issue about the `Code Signing Resource Rules Path`:

If I specify the `CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH=$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist` then I can not upload the IPA to iTunesConnect because:

```
ERROR ITMS-90339: "This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist contains an invalid key 'CFBundleResourceSpecification' in bundle
```

However, if I removed this `CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH` the `xcrun PackageApplication`  will fail as:

```
/var/folders/9v/_4lr188x5h5019b4bsq2_fyr0000gn/T/ir4fp619hu/Payload/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources
```

Any walk around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `xcrun` uses the resource path internally in its script.

The work around to is go and directly edit the script ourselves. I had the same issue and the solution i posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769529/4236572) worked for me. Thought it'd help you as well.

Comment: Besides edit the `PackageApplication` script I could also simply drop the `--sign` command line arguments to `xcrun` to avoid this issue.