# Build Xcode app using Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, automation

I have searched many websites regarding the below issue when building iOS app using Jenkins and its been said to remove `resourceRules.plist` mentioned in `PackageApplication`. My problem is I am not able to edit or save `PackageApplication` file as suggested below sites and stack overflow:
[Solution to the issue in the below error - 1](https://blog.jayway.com/2015/05/21/fixing-your-ios-build-scripts/#comment-434434)

[Solution to the issue in the below error - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370497/code-signing-resource-rules-path-fails-on-jenkins-code-sign-resource-rules-path)

I want to automate Xcode build. I followed the below tutorial to automate the app building process using Jenkins: [Tutorial to automate the app building process using Jenkins](https://www.built.io/blog/how-to-set-up-customized-jenkins-for-ios) I am using Xcode 8.1 and Mac OS 10.12.

I am getting the below error in Jenkins:

> error: /usr/bin/codesign –force
>   –preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules –sign iPhone
>   Distribution: Company Name (XXXXXXXXXX)
>   –resource-rules=/var/folders/24/fw6633nj7l310dlqcd3r67600000gp/T/HPngq5Ljzg/Payload/AppName.app/ResourceRules.plist
>   –entitlements
>   /var/folders/24/fw6633nj7l310dlqcd3r67600000gp/T/HPngq5Ljzg/entitlements_plistUgkTGfaE
>   /var/folders/24/fw6633nj7l310dlqcd3r67600000gp/T/HPngq5Ljzg/Payload/AppName.app
>   failed with error 1. Output: Warning: usage of –preserve-metadata with
>   option “resource-rules” (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)! Warning:
>   –resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
>   /var/folders/24/fw6633nj7l310dlqcd3r67600000gp/T/HPngq5Ljzg/Payload/AppName.app/ResourceRules.plist:
>   cannot read resources
>
> Failed to build
>   /Users/iosdeveloper/.jenkins/workspace/appname_ios_app/build-dir/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}-11.ipa
>   Build step ‘Xcode’ marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE